# Second Screen via Network on Windows

Tags: windows, networking, multiple-monitors

I have set up a tv in my living room connected to an old desktop (Windows 7) controlled by a nice remote control that plays tv and films easily, but now I would like to use it as a second monitor. Currently, I'm using a nice long HDMI lead, and that works fine, but I am wondering if I can connect a second screen to my laptop (Windows 8), but instead of the data being transmitted to a second screen (connected by HDMI, VGA, etc), could it be sent to another computer's screen via the network?

Comment: Do you have a computer you can have dedicated to be always connected to the TV?

Comment: Software exists to screenshare, but you'd need a dedicated something on the TV.  Even then, the price you pay is really high (not monetarily, mostly in performance, colors, clarity, resolution supported, responsiveness, etc.)  Really, it just wouldn't be worth it to not be tethered by the cable.  Just my opinion though.  I would second @ScottChamberlain's implication of an HTPC or the like.